# SQL Error: 936, SQLState: 42000, Version column added in query

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, hql, jql

```
Actual Query Created Using JQL

    @Query("insert into AudienceResponseInteraction(engagementSplitPointId,journeyAudience,eventId,audienceResponse) select ar.point.id ,ar.journeyAudience ,ar.audienceResponseEventMaster.id, ar  from AudienceResponse ar where ar.point.id=?2 and ar.audienceResponseEventMaster.id in(?3) and ar in(?1)")

Query in Logs after spring.jpa.show-sql=true

    insert into AudienceResponseInteraction ( **version**, engagementSplitPointId, audienceId, eventId, audienceResponseId ) select ?, audiencere0_.touchPointId as col_0_0_, audiencere0_.audienceId as col_1_0_, audiencere0_.eventId as col_2_0_, audiencere0_.id as col_3_0_ from AudienceResponse audiencere0_ where audiencere0_.touchPointId=? and (audiencere0_.eventId in (?)) and (audiencere0_.id in ())
```

JQL is adding version column on its own , what is wrong and how to fix

```
public class AudienceResponseInteraction extends AbstractEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2511938602547023652L;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "audienceResponseId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
  private AudienceResponse audienceResponse;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Long engagementSplitPointId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "audienceResponseMetaDataId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
  private AudienceResponseMetaData audienceResponseMetaData;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Long eventId;
  
  @Column(name = "isProcessed", nullable = false)
  private boolean isProcessed;
  
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "audienceId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
  private JourneyAudience journeyAudience;
}
```

Above Enity inherits abtract Entity, whoich has version as field

Comment: Can you paste the `AudienceResponseInteraction` entity?

Comment: Got solution after speaking with Informix DB Rep

Comment: Spoke with Informix DB Rep, about the issue , Got Reponse : query parameters are supported in onedb/informix to determine the column list, Moved to Criteriabuilder --issueResolved